# Can't connect to oracle database with IntelliJ, Locale not recognized

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have Oracle Database 11g Express Edition installed, and can normally connect to my local database with PLSQL Developer, but I can't connect with IntelliJ. It says Locale not recognized.

[image]

After searching for some similar questions here, solution was kinda to change the machine locale manually, I did that and rebooted, but it still does not work. And I'm sure it really changed, because now, this line of java code:
`System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())` printed `en_US`.

Now i really don't know what is the problem, why does PLSQL work and IntelliJ does not.

I am using ojdbc6.jar for connection.

When I tried to connect with the java code below the same kind of exception was thrown.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "SYSTEM", "password");
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1006)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:238)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at data_coonnections.DataConnector.main(DataConnector.java:15)
```

Comment: What is your java version? (jdk installed)

Comment: its jdk1.8.0_181

Comment: ojdbc6 is for JDK1.6  maybe that is your problem , use ojdbc7 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally changing Format(in Control Panel -> Clock and Region -> Region -> Format) to English (United States) did help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the regional settings of the OS you can go to the "**Advanced**" tab (see the picture that you posted) and down to the "**VM options**:" field. 
Enter `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US`.

You can also set `-Duser.region=UK` or what ever region is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC thin driver uses the Java's Locale to change your Database session language. For example I'm French, I live in France, when I connect to a Database in the US from my local system my Database session is in French. Why? That's because my Locale is configured this way. You can always override the default Locale to something else if your Locale isn't recognized by Oracle.